# Power BI dataset lookup and sorting

Tags: sorting, powerbi, dax, lookup

I have a dataset with ordernumber, productionarea and productionstart, data1, data2, data3.
The dataset is delivered in a unsorted way.The dataset looks like:

| Ordernumber | ProductionArea | ProductionDate | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| order1 | Area1 | 12/01/2023 | 5 | 3 | 9 |
| order13 | Area5 | 14/01/2023 | 6 | 2 | 4 |
| order11 | Area3 | 19/01/2023 | 7 | 9 | 5 |
| order12 | Area1 | 14/01/2023 | 8 | 8 | 6 |
| order16 | Area3 | 01/01/2023 | 9 | 7 | 7 |
| order13 | Area1 | 13/01/2023 | 8 | 6 | 8 |

What I want is a solution to **add a column (data4)** with the result from data2 from the next order. Or a solution to determine the next ordernumber from the same productionarea based on the productiondate. So for order1 I need results from order13 (which is the next one based on the startdate). With a lookup function i'm able to retrieve values from differtent columns, but I need to get **the right Next order number** first.

So In this case: order1, area1, 12/01/2023 needs a new column with the value from data2 from order13, which is the next order in area1 based on the date.

I've tried to Create a New table (referenced) and sorted it on production date, then use a filter based on the productionunit. But I dont get the results right;

I started with:

```
VAR CurrentOrderNumber = dataset[ordernumber] 
VAR CurrentArea = dataset[productionarea]
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(MIN('dataset'[ordernumber]), FILTER('dataset','dataset'[ordernumber] > CurrentOrderNumber && ('dataset'[productionarea]=CurrentArea)))
```

How to do this?
The results based on my formula are:
[image: Results]

It gives the results from order12(area1) instead of order13(area1) , if I sort on productionDate then you can see that order13 is the next in row, not order12.

Result wanted:

| Ordernumber | ProductionArea | ProductionDate | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | Data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| order1 | Area1 | 12/01/2023 | 5 | 3 | 9 | 6 |
| order13 | Area5 | 14/01/2023 | 6 | 2 | 4 |  |
| order11 | Area3 | 19/01/2023 | 7 | 9 | 5 |  |
| order12 | Area1 | 14/01/2023 | 8 | 8 | 6 |  |
| order16 | Area3 | 01/01/2023 | 9 | 7 | 7 | 2 |
| order13 | Area1 | 13/01/2023 | 8 | 6 | 8 | 9 |

OR

| Ordernumber | ProductionArea | ProductionDate | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 | NextOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| order1 | Area1 | 12/01/2023 | 5 | 3 | 9 | order13 |
| order13 | Area5 | 14/01/2023 | 6 | 2 | 4 |  |
| order11 | Area3 | 19/01/2023 | 7 | 9 | 5 |  |
| order12 | Area1 | 14/01/2023 | 8 | 8 | 6 |  |
| order16 | Area3 | 01/01/2023 | 9 | 7 | 7 | order11 |
| order13 | Area1 | 13/01/2023 | 8 | 6 | 8 | order12 |

Comment: So you want a Calculated Column adding to your existing table? if so, can you repost your first table so as to include the expected result for each row?

Comment: @JosWoolley I've updated the question with table as expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Calculated Column**:

```
=
VAR ThisProductArea = Table1[ProductionArea]
VAR ThisProductDate = Table1[ProductionDate]
VAR NextProdDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Table1[ProductionDate] ),
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[ProductionArea] = ThisProductArea
                && Table1[ProductionDate] > ThisProductDate
        )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Table1[Ordernumber] ),
        FILTER (
            Table1,
            Table1[ProductionArea] = ThisProductArea
                && Table1[ProductionDate] = NextProdDate
        )
    )
```